# delete and update on SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm deleting and updating SQLite database but after delete and update changes doesn't happen in database record

**update function:**

```
public void update(int iD, String name, String gender, String date,String branch, String mob, String email, String address) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] para = new String[7];
        para[0]= name; para[1]=gender; para[2]=date; para[3]=branch; para[4]=mob; para[5]=email; para[6]=address;
        db.execSQL("UPDATE stud SET Name=?,Gender=?,DOB=?,Branch=?,Mobile=?,EmailId=?,Address=? WHERE _id="+iD+"",para);
        System.out.println("data updated....");
    }
```

**delete function:**

```
public void deleteData(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("in del");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM stud WHERE _id='"+id+"'");
    System.out.println("data deleted...");

}
```

The statements after query are executed.
db is SQLite database variable.

Comment: any errors in your logs?

Comment: no...after delete n upates operations i'm displaying data ...it displays as it is

Comment: where are you displaying? If in listview, then have you called `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: how to that??i'm displaying data using table

Comment: Debug your app to check if it really didn't change. Or use `Log.d()`

Answer (score 0):

Call `yourcursor.requery();` after your operation finish when you use cursoradapter for listing database in listview.

Comment: there is no such requery() method